# Force explicit URL listening path for .net Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I'm deploying a .net web api to a server on port 443- but I want to be sure that it only listens to traffic on a certain URL, not just a port.

Example- I want the application to only listen to requests made on /api. If a request is made to host:443/foo, currently, the request will return 404 from my application. I don't want this to. happen for two reasons- one: it could potentially interfere with other traffic- there's nothing else running on this port currently, but if there was in the future, I don't want anything to break. And two: this could clutter my logs on the long term.

My desired outcome is for the application to completely ignore/not even know about requests to any URL other than host:443/api. I figured that the app.UsePathBase method would accomplish this, but no such luck.

Is this possible? Or is this kind of implementation not recommended? Should I just choose an obscure port and not worry about it?

Comment: Talking about urls, we are at the Application OSI layer. So, first option - is to use reverse proxy (with nginx, apache or [yarp](https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy), for example). Other option - configure hosting web server (like [IIS filtering feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis)), which urls to listen, if your app is not self-hosted.

Comment: Talking about ports (Transport OSI layer) - Even if that's possible (using SocketOption.ReuseAddress,  SocketOption.ReusePort), i would call it intentional troublemaking. Never saw such sort of configuration (application trying to use already reserved socket i.e interface-port just fails to start - typical behavior). So, the only use case imho for socket options above - scaling your [web-]server with mulitiple processes, using some lower-level load-balancer (which is essentially a reverse-proxy too).

Comment: @Ryan Sounds like I'm trying to go about this in a way that is not recommended. If reverse proxying is the way to go, yarp looks interesting- but if I'm reverse proxying from the application itself, won't the requests still be intercepted?

I would just use NGINX as I've used it in the past, but the cert that I need to use is having some issues being converted to the format nginx requires

Comment: If you deploy the web app as self hosted and hook to Windows HTTP API with reserved URL, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#reserved-urls then thing should work as you wished.

Answer (score 0):

> but if I'm reverse proxying from the application itself, won't the requests still be intercepted?

Not sure what u are talking about. One of the reverse-proxy aspects  - cut-off undesired traffic for target host. That traffic comes entirely to other host (reverse-proxy), and then gets filtered.
Reverse-proxing from the application itslef is a nonsense.